# Differential Equation Special Case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a DEQ that has a special case.

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} +4 \dfrac{dy}{dx} + 4y = e^{-2x}$$

I understand my general solution will be: $ Ae^{-2x} + Bxe^{-2x} $, however my problem is dealing with the particular for the $e^{-2x} $ on the RHS. I thought of this: $ Ce^{-2x} + Dxe^{-2x} + Ex^2e^{-2x}$. How would I deal with the $e$ on the RHS and solve the DE EQ?

Comment: Is it written correctly?  **Hint:** Choose $y_p(x) = c x^2 e^{-2x}$, substitute into the ODE, solve for $c$.

Comment: Just to point out that whatever Ansatz you choose to try as a particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation, you don't want to include the solutions to the homogeneous equation. This is because the LHS will automatically send those terms to zero, so it a waste of algebra.  Thus your Ansatz should not include linear combinations of $e^{-2x}$ and $xe^{-2x}$ and therefore @Variable's suggestion is a very sensible one.

Comment: @Variable I thought by adding linear factors I would get a solution, but that left me with more unknowns. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already correctly shown the homogeneous solution to be $$y_h = Ae^{-2x}+Bxe^{-2x}$$ But when you're looking to build a particular solution you might first think that $$y_p = Ce^{-2x}$$ But that isn't right since there is an $e^{-2x}$ term in the homoegeneous, so now multiply by $x$, and you know see that this too exists in the homoegeneous solution, now finally multiply by another $x$ and you have the particular solution you're looking for $$y_p = Cx^2e^{-2x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} +4 \dfrac{dy}{dx} + 4y = e^{-2x}$$

You found the general solution  $ Y(x)=Ae^{-2x} + Bxe^{-2x}$ of the homogeneous equation : $\dfrac{d^2Y}{dx^2} +4 \dfrac{dY}{dx} + 4Y = 0$

If you look for only one particular solution $y_p$ of the inhomogeneous equation, no need for $ Ae^{-2x}$ and $Bxe^{-2x}$ Only one is sufficient : $ Ae^{-2x}$ or $Bxe^{-2x}$.

For example, consider $ Ae^{-2x}$ and replace the constant $A$ by an unknown function $f(x)$, i.e.: $$y_p=f(x)e^{-2x}$$

$y_p'=(f'-2f)e^{-2x}$ and $y_p''=(f''-4f'+4f)e^{-2x}$

puting them into the inhomogeneous equation gives :

$(f''-4f'+4f+4(f'-2f)+4f)e^{-2x}=e^{-2x}$ which is simplified to :
$$f''=1$$
$$f=\frac{x^2}{2}+c_1 x+c_2$$
$$y=(\frac{x^2}{2}+c_1 x+c_2)e^{-2x}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write $(\frac{d}{dx} + 2)f = e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}(e^{2x}f)$. Your equation is
$$
        \left(\frac{d}{dx}+2\right)^2f = e^{-2x} \\
           \left(e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x}\right)^2f = e^{-2x}
$$
Now apply another factor of $(\frac{d}{dx}+2)$ to both sides:
$$
         \left(e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x}\right)^3f = \left(e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x}\right)e^{-2x}=0 \\
                  e^{-2x}\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(e^{2x}f)=0, \\
            e^{2x}f = A+Bx+Cx^2 \\
               f = (A+Bx+Cx^2)e^{-2x}
$$
When you plug into the original equation
$$
         \left(e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x}\right)^2\left[(A+Bx+Cx^2)e^{-2x}\right] \\
     = e^{-2x}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(A+Bx+Cx^2)
     = 2Ce^{-2x}
$$
So you want $2C=1$ or $C=1/2$. The general solution of your problem is
$$
                f = \left(A+Bx+\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)e^{-2x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write $(\frac{d}{dx} + 2)f = e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}(e^{2x}f)$. Your equation is
$$
        \left(\frac{d}{dx}+2\right)^2f = e^{-2x} \\
           \left(e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x}\right)^2f = e^{-2x}
$$
Now apply $(\frac{d}{dx}+2)$ to both sides:
$$
         \left(e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x}\right)^3f = \left(e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x}\right)e^{-2x}=0 \\
                  e^{-2x}\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(e^{2x}f)=0, \\
            e^{2x}f = A+Bx+Cx^2 \\
               f = (A+Bx+Cx^2)e^{-2x}
$$
When you plug into the original equation
$$
         \left(e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}e^{2x}\right)^2\left[(A+Bx+Cx^2)e^{-2x}\right] \\
     = e^{-2x}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(A+Bx+Cx^2)
     = 2Ce^{-2x}
$$
So you want $2C=1$ or $C=1/2$. The general solution of your problem is
$$
                f = \left(A+Bx+\frac{1}{2}x^2\right)e^{-2x}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I would opt to use differential operators in this case.
This consist of finding $y_p$ (particular solution) and $y_c$ (complementary function).
Attempting $y_p$

The formula is as follows
$\frac{1}{(D-a)^r}$$e^{ax}$=$\frac{x^r}{r!}$$e^{ax}$

So for $y_p$($D^2$+$4D$+$4$)=$e^{-2x}$

$y_p$=$\frac{e^{-2x}}{D^2+4D+4}$=$\frac{x^2}{2!}$$e^{-2x}$

=$\frac{x^2}{2}$$e^{-2x}$

Finding $y_c$ is (A+B$x$)$e^{-2x}$

Hence $y$=$y_p$+$y_c$= (A+B$x$+$\frac{x^2}{2}$)$e^{-2x}$